# Need help to parse html codes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm parsing html codes and got stuck. I wish somebody help me with it.for detail codes please follow this link : http://regexr.com?369sg

I want to get any match with:

```
<td class="weekday reservation alternate fixwidth calday fixwidth " > ? </td><!--1-->
<td class="weekend reservation alternate fixwidth calday fixwidth " > ? </td><!--2-->
<td class="weekday calday fixwidth">&nbsp;</td><!--3-->
<td class="weekend calday fixwidth">&nbsp;</td><!--4-->
```

if I use this pattern:

```
/<td class="(weekday|weekend) reservation (primary|alternate) fixwidth calday fixwidth " >(.*?)<\/td>/
```

I only got number 1 and 2,
if I use this pattern:

```
/<td class="(weekday|weekend) calday fixwidth">(.*?)<\/td>/
```

I only got number 3,4.

How to match with all of number (1,2,3,4) above using one pattern?
I'm using preg_match_all function anyway.

Please help me, Thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

Apart that you'd better to use an html parser, here is a regex that do the job:

```
/<td class="(weekday|weekend) (?:reservation (primary|alternate) fixwidth )?calday fixwidth " >(.*?)<\/td>/
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I'm required by Stack Overflow to say something bad about using regular expressions to scrape HTML:

- *DON'T* use regular expressions as a stand alone parser.
- *DO* use regular expressions if you're just trying to find some strings wtihin some text and features of the language do not matter.

So here's a new regular expression:

```
<td.+?class="(?:weekday|weekend)(?:\s+reservation\s+(?:primary|alternate)\s+fixwidth\s+|\s+)calday fixwidth.*?"[^>]*>(.+?)</td>
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/7d9tyf)

- `<td.+?class=`: This will allow you to have anything in between `<td` and `class`.  So if you have other attributes you'll be cool.  Do note lazy quantifiers like `+?` have a performance penalty.  So don't do this a million times.
- `(?:weekday|weekend)`: Pretty much the same that you had before, except it is a non capturing group.  I use the non capturing groups so that `$matches[1]` will have the code you're looking for.
- `(?:\s+reservation\s+(?:primary|alternate)\s+fixwidth\s+|\s+)`: This will match either the string in the first two examples, or just a space for last two.  I considered just doing `.+?`, if those classes aren't important do that instead.
- `calday fixwidth.*?"`: This allows for any additional classes.
- `"[^>]*>`: This allows for more attributes, but it is better performing than `.*?`.
- `(.+?)</td>`: End of pattern.

One note, this will fail if you have nested matches and you will need to use a parser instead:

```
<td class="weekday calday fixwidth">
   <table><tr>
      <td class="weekday calday fixwidth">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr></table>
</td>
```

The result would have one match:

```
    <td class="weekday calday fixwidth">
   <table><tr>
      <td class="weekday calday fixwidth">&nbsp;</td>
```

And group 1 would be:

```
  <table><tr>
      <td class="weekday calday fixwidth">&nbsp;
```

**Alternative**

Instead of such a specific pattern, I would try the more flexible alternative instead:

```
<td.+?class="(?:[^"]*(?:weekday|weekend|primary|alternate|calday|fixwidth)){3,}[^"]*"[^>]*>(.+?)</td>
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/pmztgn)

This uses a look ahead to try to match a `td` that has a `class` attribute with at least three instances within the alternation.